# as3 netstream sends StreamNotFound on all mp3's, not on mp4's

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mp3, netstream

I've developed a custom video player which needs to double up as an audio player. All the functionality is there, but the NetStream doesn't load the mp3. It throws NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound.

I am not using a Flash Media server. I have tested both local, and online .mp3 files. 
The strange thing is that the code works perfectly when putting in an .mp4 file.

What am I missing?

Comment: you are missing the code..post up! We don't want to take guesses as to how you coded this

Comment: Ok, the reason I didn't is because it's quite a lot and I thought I might be hitting an obvious 'that's not possible' thing. But you're right, will post code now, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not using media server or desktop application it wont work. `mp4` is a container format for both video and audio, thats why netStream is loading it: Its reading it as an empty video stream with an active sound stream. In the other hand, `mp3` is an audio only codec, and you should load it using the `Sound` class, not `NetStream`. Here is some more info about supported formats for NetStream objects: http://dev.illumifi.net/AS3/flash/net/NetStream.html